# Can't post a network update

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-j

I am using linkedin-j for authenticating an managing linkedin API in java. I have no problems in getting user info, email address and so. Even I don't have problems posting a share:

```
final LinkedInApiClientFactory factory = LinkedInApiClientFactory.newInstance(consumerKeyValue, consumerSecretValue);
final LinkedInApiClient client = factory.createLinkedInApiClient(token, secret);
client.postShare(title, text, title, title, VisibilityType.ANYONE);
```

I see it immediately in my linkedin timeline, but when I try to post a network update I get no erros but the update doesn't show in the timeline

```
final LinkedInApiClientFactory factory = LinkedInApiClientFactory.newInstance(consumerKeyValue, consumerSecretValue);
final LinkedInApiClient client = factory.createLinkedInApiClient(token, secret);
client.postNetworkUpdate(update);
```

Does anybody have this same problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I found this answer:
"postNetworkStatus() is whitelisted for apps in development (see the LinkedIn? developer documentation). You need to add all the testing accounts as developers of the app. Otherwise this method does silently fail" but my users are already developers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer I found was right:
"postNetworkStatus() is whitelisted for apps in development (see the LinkedIn? developer documentation). You need to add all the testing accounts as developers of the app. Otherwise this method does silently fail"

but I think that I took some time for the developer accounts to work. Now it works perfectly.